# Is there the Windows 10+ calculator copy-paste syntax?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, calculator

I know that you can paste in calc.exe expression with the **/+-^*()** operators. Does anyone know is there other operations and how to paste the **Pi** number?

"pi" and pi unicode symbol seem to cause *"Error input"*

Comment: "how to paste the Pi number?" – I guess `3.14`… should work.

Comment: Click the 3 bars at the top left of the calculator and change it from standard to scientific mode. You will then have access to a pi button, otherwise - you just have to enter the 3.14159... number yourself

Comment: @Narzard I know about this. My question is about paste expressions exactly. You can answer that where is no such feature, that's all